# QFileIconProvider always use "gnome" theme?

Tags: linux, qt, qt4.8

Is there a way to let user choose what icon theme to use , when using QFIleIconProvider ? It looks like Qt uses "gnome" by default , i wanted to change this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon style is dependent on what is returned from QApplication::style(). So if you change the application style using [QApplication::setStyle()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#setStyle), you'll get a different set of icons too. If you want a different theme than the application style, you need to subclass QFileIconProvider and set you custom icon provider with `QFileSystemModel::setIconProvider(yourCustomIconProvider)`.